# Different element width and CSS width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, width

When I look at an element using FF inspector, it shows 225px width for that.
But CSS width: 207px is applied for this element.
Clue is bootstrap. I think it causes this difference by different resolutions.
Also is there a tool which reveals change sources?
I mean a tool to notify when special property changed.
Thank in advance for any help

These are taken from FF Inspector in two states:
Element is **input[type=text]**

```html
<input aria-invalid="true" class="invalid" name="jform[university]" id="jform_university" value="" required="" aria-required="true" type="text">
```

**State 1: Width = 225px**

```css
*::-moz-selection {
    background: #F9924F none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    color: #FFF;
}
element {
}
select, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
    width: 207px;
    max-width: 207px !important;
}
.form-search input, .form-search textarea, .form-search select, .form-search .help-inline, .form-search .uneditable-input, .form-search .input-prepend, .form-search .input-append, .form-inline input, .form-inline textarea, .form-inline select, .form-inline .help-inline, .form-inline .uneditable-input, .form-inline .input-prepend, .form-inline .input-append, .form-horizontal input, .form-horizontal textarea, .form-horizontal select, .form-horizontal .help-inline, .form-horizontal .uneditable-input, .form-horizontal .input-prepend, .form-horizontal .input-append {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
    background-color: #FFF;
    transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.2s linear 0s;
}
select, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #CACACA;
    color: #424242;
    background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
.form-search input, .form-inline input, .form-horizontal input, .form-search textarea, .form-inline textarea, .form-horizontal textarea, .form-search select, .form-inline select, .form-horizontal select, .form-search .help-inline, .form-inline .help-inline, .form-horizontal .help-inline, .form-search .uneditable-input, .form-inline .uneditable-input, .form-horizontal .uneditable-input, .form-search .input-prepend, .form-inline .input-prepend, .form-horizontal .input-prepend, .form-search .input-append, .form-inline .input-append, .form-horizontal .input-append {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
body, a, input, .jm-title, .jm-module, .btn {
    font-family: Yekan !important;
}
input, textarea, .uneditable-input {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
label, input, button, select, textarea {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 20px;
}
input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 18px;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #555;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
label, input, button, select, textarea {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 18px;
}
button, input {
    line-height: normal;
}
button, input, select, textarea {
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
body {
    color: #6A6A6A;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
}
body {
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #333;
}
html {
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

**State 2: Width = 207px**

```css
*::-moz-selection {
    background: #F9924F none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    color: #FFF;
}
element {
}
select, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
    width: 207px;
    max-width: 207px !important;
}
.form-search input, .form-search textarea, .form-search select, .form-search .help-inline, .form-search .uneditable-input, .form-search .input-prepend, .form-search .input-append, .form-inline input, .form-inline textarea, .form-inline select, .form-inline .help-inline, .form-inline .uneditable-input, .form-inline .input-prepend, .form-inline .input-append, .form-horizontal input, .form-horizontal textarea, .form-horizontal select, .form-horizontal .help-inline, .form-horizontal .uneditable-input, .form-horizontal .input-prepend, .form-horizontal .input-append {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
    background-color: #FFF;
    transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.2s linear 0s;
}
select, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #CACACA;
    color: #424242;
    background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
.form-search input, .form-inline input, .form-horizontal input, .form-search textarea, .form-inline textarea, .form-horizontal textarea, .form-search select, .form-inline select, .form-horizontal select, .form-search .help-inline, .form-inline .help-inline, .form-horizontal .help-inline, .form-search .uneditable-input, .form-inline .uneditable-input, .form-horizontal .uneditable-input, .form-search .input-prepend, .form-inline .input-prepend, .form-horizontal .input-prepend, .form-search .input-append, .form-inline .input-append, .form-horizontal .input-append {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
body, a, input, .jm-title, .jm-module, .btn {
    font-family: Yekan !important;
}
input, textarea, .uneditable-input {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
label, input, button, select, textarea {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 20px;
}
input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 18px;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #555;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
label, input, button, select, textarea {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 18px;
}
button, input {
    line-height: normal;
}
button, input, select, textarea {
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
body {
    color: #6A6A6A;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
}
body {
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #333;
}
html {
    font-size: 100%;
```

Comment: there must be some `padding` within the element plus borders (if any), that padding increases the `width` of elements unless you specify `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: There are so much reasons that would explain this behavior, so without additional information we can't judge anything (and thus, not suggest any solution). Can you provide information about the computed styles, the actual css selectors applied, the content of the element?

Comment: @RohitKumar, padding is same in both widths. Definitely this difference is not generated by padding.

Comment: @DominikSchreiber, I agree with you. There can bo so much reasons. But if there was a tool which fires an even in width change could help. BTW I edited the question and I add more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you have `width:207px` set on your input and ask yourself (and us) why it shows up with `225px` width on the page.

You seem to be running into css [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) computations.

---

By default (and that's the mode you're in because you didn't specify anything else) boxes are in `box-sizing:content-box` mode. What you want is `box-sizing:border-box` as it almost always behaves more natural. To apply this on an element you have to set the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property on it.

[image]
<sub>(source: [binvisions.com](http://www.binvisions.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/css-box-model-border-content_590x328.jpg))</sub>

### content-box

Computes the `width`/`height` of an element *only from its content*. That means `padding`, `border-width` and `margin` are all "outside" the dimensions of the element.

When you specify `width:207px` in this model this means "the content of this element should be 207 px wide". Padding and border-width get added to that.

#### border-box

Adds `padding` and `border-width` to this computation. The `width` is now the sum of content + padding + border-width.

Specifying `width:207px` with `padding:8px` and `border-width:1px` means there are `207px - 2*8px - 2*1px = 189px` room for the content.

---

#### problem-specific solution

You apply

```css
select, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
    width: 207px;
}

select, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
    padding: 0 8px;
    border: 1px solid #CACACA;
}
```

As you are in `content-box` mode, the computed width is `207px + 2*8px + 2*1px` which is exactly `225px` what you observed.

**apply `box-sizing:border-box` to the element and it works.** But beware that might break everything else with that style. Maybe you're better off with applying `width:189px` to it.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. My unclear model is related to Box-Model. Even with width: 207px !important, in different resolution, it shows different widths. Please take a look at pictures at below of question

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow did not alow me to add pictures. But his is all I've got. With css (width: 207px !important, same padding, margin, border-width),In screen resolution > 980px, width becomes width(207)+padding(8+8)+broder(1+1)=225px, but in resolution < 980, with same css width becomes width(189)+padding(8+8)+border(1+1)=207px. These bumbers are from FF inspector - BOX-MODEL.

Comment: I found the width change reason in box-sizing as you mentioned. Twitter-Bootstrap in resolution <980px add box-sizing: border-box to these elements. But is there any tool to reveal the change source ???

Comment: I usually use Chrome as I really like the [DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) there. But even FF DevTools will have something like "Computed Styles", where they show you what actually gets applied to the element. There you may spot the differences.

Comment: I can see this issue in both FF and chrome, in their computed styles. However, i'm using the word ISSUE so carefully. BTW thank for your help